# No funciona DataTable con una tabla creada desde ajax

Tags: javascript, html, c#, datatables, asp.net-core

Tengo un DataTable que lo muestro desde html, pero al presionar un boton quiero que me actualice esa tabla, y lo hago con la siguiente funcion:

```
function Cantidad() {
    var IDPRODUCTOBODEGAS = $('#IDPRODUCTOBODEGAS').val();
    var CANTIDADES = $('#CANTIDADES').val();

    var data = { IDPRODUCTOBODEGAS: IDPRODUCTOBODEGAS, CANTIDADES: CANTIDADES };
    var opciones = '<table id="inventario" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%; text-align:center;">'+
                    '<thead>'+
                        '<tr> '+
                            '<th hidden> IDPRODUCTO_BODEGA </th>'+
                            '<th> PRODUCTO </th>'+
                            '<th> CATEGORIA </th>'+
                            '<th> </th>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                   '</thead></table> ';

    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Factura/CantidadProductos',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                console.log(value.idproductobodega);
                
                opciones += '<tbody>'+
                              '<tr>'+
                                '<td id="IDPRODUCTOBODEGA" hidden>'+ value.idproductobodega +'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ value.producto +'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ value.categoria +'</td>'+
                                '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #6F6E6B; border-color: #ebce5b;" onclick="SeleccionarProducto('+ value.idproductobodega +')">Seleccionar</a></td>'+
                              '</tr>'+
                           '</tbody>'
            });
            $('#inventario').html(opciones);
        }

    });
}
```

La funcion funciona bien, me muestra la tabla ya con datos actualizados, el problema es que no me deja usar las funciones del DataTable como la barra de busqueda.

Asi es como declaro la tabla como DataTable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inventario').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',

        "language": {
            url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.12.1/i18n/es-ES.json"
        }
    });
});
```

Entonces no se como es que se puede crear un DataTable con datos que vienen desde un ajax, porque si necesito esa funcion de la barra de busqueda.

Espero me ayuden, saludos.

Comment: Hola ivon, cada vez que ejecutas la llamada AJAX estás destruyendo el DataTable al pisar el HTML en `#inventario`. Si lo destruís, lo tenes que volver a crear.

Comment: Y como hago eso @Marcos

Comment: Exactamente igual que en el `$(document).ready()`. PD: Deberías agregar una sola vez el `tbody`, no por cada registro. El `</table>` deberías hacerlo al finalizar todo.

Comment: Ya esta, muchas gracias @Marcos